# Is there a vim plugin for Python that will check if a non-existant object is called from a package?

Tags: python, vim, plugins

I have been using the [flake 8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) python extension, which when ran will tell me whether a variable is not defined, if there are too many white spaces, etc. But flake8 will not produce an error if I call a nonexistent object from some package. For example, the following will not produce an error with flake8:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.aa_bb_cc()
```

`np.aa_bb_cc()` does not exist so I would like to have a plug in that would tell me so before I run my python script. Is there a plugin that will produce an error for the above? For example, this feature is built into Visual Studio Code but I would like to also be able to have this same feature in vim if possible.

Comment: [tag:syntastic]  or [tag:vim-ale] + flake8 + pylint + mypy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install pylint then create a vim map to run it from within vim.

```
nnoremap <leader>l :!python3 -m pylint % <bar> grep no-member<cr>
```

Notes: I'm using `<leader>l` but it could be anything else. Also, `<bar> grep no-member` will only output the error you're looking for. Remove it to see other pylint warnings.

Comment: Sorry to the late reply, but pylint is not doing what I asked for in the original question. If I have a python file with `import numpy as np` and the top and then in a later line, type `x = np.abcd()`, no error is given.

Comment: python2? I guess no-member is only on 3

Comment: no I'm using python 3.10

Comment: just tried on a python:3.10-alpine docker container (https://imgur.com/a/aUw64m1) what output do you get from pylint in a case like this?

Comment: this is weird... I tried your example with `os` and I got what you got. I then did `import shutil` followed by `shutil.ppp()` and also got an error. I though that it may have to do with preinstalled packages, like `os` and `shutil`, versus post installed packages like `numpy`, but then I tried `import tensorflow as tf` followed by `tf.ppp()` and `import scipy` followed by `scipy.meannnn()` and also received an error for both. So I am unsure why it is not working for `numpy`